# How do I add multiple totals in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the total amount for each method of payment listed in a table.
I have the sum of each row, and now I need to add those sums.
The query is:

```
select payment_method, (deposit + pet_deposit + cleaning_fee + rental_rate) as            
total
from reservations
group by total
order by payment_method;
```

and this is the result set:

```
+----------------+---------+
| payment_method | total   |
+----------------+---------+
| Check          |  760.00 |
| Check          |  960.00 |
| Check          |  660.00 |
| MasterCard     |  600.00 |
| MasterCard     | 1160.00 |
| PayPal         |  500.00 |
| Visa           |  560.00 |
| Visa           |  610.00 |
| Visa           |  700.00 |
+----------------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How would I make it so there's only instance of each payment method, and the total column has the full total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html) the payment method, like this:

```
SELECT payment_method, 
     SUM(deposit + pet_deposit + cleaning_fee + rental_rate) 
          AS total
FROM reservations
GROUP BY payment_method
ORDER BY payment_method;
```

Your result should then look like this (sample data in sums):

```
+----------------+---------+
| payment_method | total   |
+----------------+---------+
| Check          |  123.45 |
| MasterCard     |  234.56 |
| PayPal         |  345.67 |
| Visa           |  456.78 |
+----------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by payment method instead of total.

Comment: When I do this it doesn't show the actual total, it just shows the initial total and doesn't add the other instances.